# Variables not shown in company-mode

Tags: company-mode, documentation, variables

I use `company-mode` for auto-completion and sometimes I have a strange problem with Emacs-Lisp. Variables are not shown among the completion candidates. Sometimes, if shown, pressing `<f1>` doesn't open any documentation. I have to shut down Emacs and reboot. This behavior seems to be completely random. Any hint?

(By the way: this used to happen also when I was using auto-complete-mode)

Comment: I guess this depends on the company backend. For which language do you get this behaviour?

Comment: I edited the question. I was referring to Emacs-Lisp. Thank you.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem reliably?

Comment: No. It's quite random.

Comment: Ok. But if you have that problem in a given session, does it remain if you abort and re-initiate completion, or is it most likely gone?

Comment: Usually, it's gone. I just have to shut down Emacs and launch it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the [issue](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/258), the author of this question expected to see the documentation for variables from a package that hasn't been loaded yet.

`M-x describe-variable` won't show it either, so it's not a bug.

Comment: Just tested. `M-x describe variable` works fine but I still cannot see among the completion candidates e.g. `org-agenda-block-separator` if I'm inside a custom command's settings. Let me explain better. In this case:

`(setq org-agenda-b...)`  
  
I can see the variable among the completions, but in the case of `(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(("b" "Test" (...) ((org-agenda-b...)))))`, I cannot.

Comment: @petrux That seems to be a bug in `elisp-completion-at-point` (which was called `lisp-completion-at-point` until recently). You should `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @petrux Thanks. If no one beats me to it, I should get around to it in a few days.

Comment: @petrux And it's fixed now. Sorry it took a while.